# How to initialize JS most efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smoothstate.js

I am using AJAX to load pages, and am wondering what is the most efficient way to initialize JS that is stored in an external sheet on every page load. I have just made a bunch of functions and one "container" function that I call whenever `load()` is finished inserting content.

Basically:

```
function initContainer() {

  functionOne();
  functonTwo();
  functionThree();
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

I have a quite complex site/app, and there is a lot of functions. It seems very inefficient and bad, but I am not having any problems per se. Am just wondering what I can do to make this better.

I am using [**smoothState.js**](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js?files=1) for some of the page loads and it only has one `onAfter` hook, therefore I must have a function like `initContainer()` because I dont't really know which page is gonna get loaded and which functions I am going to use.

Thank you

Comment: You can make use of async and defer attributes on your script tag: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html But make sure you **understand** what they do before using them, or else you'll run into problems. Other than that, you'll have to explain more clearly what it is you want. Is it minimizing the file size? Minimizing the time it takes to run?

Comment: My app is not experiencing any performance issues at all. What I am asking is if this is inefficient. My JS loads at the bottom of the page in a single file. There is no <script> on the loaded pages. Everything is in the same file.

Comment: learn about [tag:wepack] + [tag:reactjs] + [tag-react-router] ,then , your life will change

Comment: @Svedr Can you elaborate more on what you mean by inefficient? What are your concerns?

Comment: If you're not having any performance problems, then what exactly is motivating your desire to change anything??

Comment: I love reactjs, but sadly the back-end for the app that I am currently working on is not based on an API and everything is rendered server-side with Java in .jsp pages.